# dynamically adding columns from LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, dynamic, left-join, multiple-columns

I have the following tables :

Users:

```
+---------------------------+
| id    | e-mail            |
+---------------------------+
| 1     | john@domain.com   |
+---------------------------+
| 2     | jane@domain.com   |
+---------------------------+
| 3     | mark@domain.com   |
+---------------------------+
```

Books:

```
+-------------------------------+
| id    | user_id   | value     |
+-------------------------------+
| 1     | 1         | ABC       |
+-------------------------------+
| 2     | 1         | HIJ       |
+-------------------------------+
| 3     | 2         | XYZ       |
+-------------------------------+
```

I'd like to build a query to get the following results:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| user_id   | e-mail            | value_1   | value_2   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 1         | john@domain.com   | ABC       | HIJ       |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 2         | jane@domain.com   | XYZ       | NULL      |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 3         | mark@domain.com   | NULL      | NULL      |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

So the result columns are built dynamically depending on the max numbers of books. If john@domain.com had a third book, then the result table should contain 3 "value" columns and this column would be NULL for jane@domain.com and mark@domain.com.
Is such a thing possible in MySQL?

Comment: Looks like classic `PIVOT`

Comment: Directly not possible (short of indulging in dyanamic SQL in a stored procedure). If you are prepared to go to that length (and I would suggest that you are trying to put the presentation of the data into the database calls) then one query could return the max number of values per user id, and then use that to dynamically build a query for a pivoted result set.

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, took this as a challenge.

This following is a stored procedure that should dynamically build the required SQL and execute it, returning the result set. Seems to work with my test copies of you tables (assuming your column name of e-mail was meant to be e_mail).

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE dynamic_table()
BEGIN
    DECLARE max_count_var INT;
    DECLARE v_counter INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE base_sql TEXT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS max_count FROM Books GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max_count DESC LIMIT 1 INTO max_count_var;

    SET base_sql = 'SELECT a.id AS user_id, a.e_mail ';

    WHILE v_counter <= max_count_var DO
        SET base_sql = CONCAT(base_sql, ',MAX(IF(cnt=', v_counter, ', `value`, NULL)) AS value_', v_counter);
        SET v_counter = v_counter + 1;
    END WHILE;

    SET base_sql = CONCAT(@s, ' FROM Users a LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT id, user_id, value, @cnt:=IF(@user_id = user_id, @cnt + 1, 1) AS cnt, @user_id := user_id FROM Books CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt:=1, @user_id:=0) sub0 ORDER BY user_id, id ) b ON a.id = b.user_id GROUP BY a.id, a.e_mail ORDER BY a.id');

    SET @s = base_sql;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This looks really great, but it triggers an error when I try to run it : `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1` I'm using MySQL 5.6

Comment: That is just the bits of syntax you need to use to enter stored proceedures depending on the development environment you are using (it is a bit of a pain!). Try deleting the double semi colons after end along with the last line.